# Find the one that appears an odd number of times. Odd apears once

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function findOdd(A) {

  var count = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    for( let j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
       if(A[i]=== A[j]){
          count = count + 1;
        }
        if(count % 2 ===0){
            count = 0;
        }else{
          var n = A[i];
          }
     }

    
   }    
  return n
  
}
```

**This is my code, i used nested for, and outcome always is the last element of the array, why?**

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: @otejiri is a codewars exercise, the function name is findOdd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last iteration, `i = A.length`, and `j = A.length`.  You then check if `A[i] === A[j]`, they are.  You set `count = count + 1`, so it will be `1` (almost always, since there is only one odd, and anytime a count is even you set `count = 0`).  `1 % 2 !== 0` so you effectively will (almost) always set `n` to `A[A.length -1]`

```js
const findOdd = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // arr[i] is the first instance, so set count to 1
        let count = 1;
        // start checking at the next element
        for (let j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            // if they are the same, increment count
            if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
                count++;
                // remove the current element, so we don't 
                // check it again using i
                arr.splice(j, 1);
                // go back, since we need to re-check this index since
                // we just removed the item that was at this index
                j--;
            }
        }
        // if it's odd, return now
        if (count % 2 !== 0) return arr[i];
    }          
}

console.log(findOdd(['a','a','b','b','c','d','d']))
```